# weird apache2/domain redirect

Tags: server, apache2, redirect

I got a few domains pointing to my ubuntu 20.04.6 server via a record.
I am using apache2 with virtual hosts for all the domains, it always worked great.
But since today i got some weird redirects going on - as soon as i want to access my website, i get redirected to some weird advertising and weird malicious sites.

My configuration did not change from my side - how is this possible?
How can i fix this behaviour / find out what is the cause?

I would be very thankfull for some help, it is very urgent and i dont know what to do, i checked some configs but all seems untouched for me...

Comment: Are you certain this is an issue with Apache and not the website code itself? A good place to start would be the document root directories for the affected site(s). See if there have been any recent modifications. If the site files are managed via source control, force a reload of the current release to clear out anything that might have been modified by a bad actor.